# Com CSS existe alguma forma de colocar opacity no currentColor?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estou tentado fazer o `box-shadow` herdar a cor da sombra de forma "dinâmica", pegando a cor setada no `color` através do `currentColor`. Até ai tudo bem, só que a cor é "sólida", não estou conseguindo dar transparência nela.

Repare nesse exemplo. A primeira div é o esperado, mas a cor da sombre fica muito forte, queria dar uma atenuada nela usando `opacity` de alguma forma, mas mantendo a herança do `currentColor`. Já tentei de vária formas a ideia seria algo como

`box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba((--cor), .25);` ou até `box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(currentColor, .25);`

Mas nenhuma delas funciona, **não queria ter que usar um pseudo-elemento como `::after`**. E um detalhe, todas as cores da lib estão em `hexa`, então não posso muda-las para `rgb()`:

```css
:root {
    --cor: #ff0000;
}
div {

    width: max-content;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 20px;
    
    color: var(--cor);
    
    border: 2px solid currentColor;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 currentColor; 
   
}

div + div {

    --cor: blue;
    /* assim tive que coloca a cor em hardcode para funcionar */
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,255,0.25); 
   
}
```

```html
<div>sombra usando o currentColor</div>
<div>queria o currentColor com transparencia</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Essa é uma resposta a pedido do usuário @CmteCardeal***

Como dito no comentário, usei o quarto valor da propriedade `box-shadow` para dar um jeitinho... Esse valor é conhecido como `spread`, e ao usar um **valor negativo** nele a sobra fica "mais para dentro" do elemento, e para corrigir o fato da sombra ir mais para dentro eu aumentei o `blur`, e assim consegui atenuar bem a sambra mantendo a cor dela com o `currentColor`.

Para mim ficou satisfatório, e foi a forma que apliquei no final das contas... Leia o comment que deixei no código do CSS

```css
:root {
    --cor: #ff0000;
}
div {

    width: max-content;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    
    color: var(--cor);
    
    border: 2px solid currentColor;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 currentColor; 
   
}

div + div {

    /* repare nos valores que usei no box-shadow, 
       coloquei um valor de -5px no spread 
       e aumente o valor do blue em 5px */
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px currentColor; 
   
}
```

```html
<div>sombra usando o <b>currentColor</b> e sem spread no box-shadow</div>
<div>sombra usando o <b>currentColor</b> e um <b>spread negativo</b> no box-shadow</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Css não é JavaScript, se você chamar a função `var(--cor)` será retornado, só e somente o valor da propriedade --cor. Então logicamente não ocorrerá nenhuma conversão de `--cor: #FF0000` para um spread de `255, 0, 0`, e o que foi armazenado em `currentColor` continua a ser #ff0000, diferente de javascript onde tudo é uma expressão, css é uma linguagem de marcação como HTML.
E a não ser que haja uma função pré-definida para retornar exatamente um valor puro, mais nada ocorrerá na marcação.
Mas na verdade já existe essa função pré-definida no módulo [color do Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#scale). E também há a opção de alteração em runtime com JavaScript usando [plugin do CssNext](https://cssnext.github.io/features/#color-function).

Por final a funcionalidade `css-mod`, a qual servirá para converter valores de cores, ainda [está sendo escrita na W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/) para uso, mas ainda não foi adotada por nenhum browser.

Comment: Valeu a resposta amigo, mas o output do SASS não é o que eu espero ele não vai resolver o problema, e implementar uma LIB com JS para resolver isso muito menos rss... Acabei resolvendo de forma satisfatória com o valor de `spread-radius` do `box-shadow`

Comment: @hugocsl sei que é atrasado, mas pode colocar uma resposta de como você fez? Sua pergunta esta como favorita porque tambem quero saber :).

Comment: @CmteCardeal me da uns 10 min que já posto a solução que usei, mas como disse, foi no "jeitinho brasileiro"...